¿Donde esta definido el Arbol jerarquico de archivos en linux?
Estoy intentando entender como funciona el árbol de carpetas de Linux versión (0.96),   y me gustaría encontrar el trozo de código donde se crean las carpetas como bin root etc..., pero no lo encuentro, he buscado en internet y lo único que encuentro son tutoriales para que es cada carpeta, también he buscado dentro de la carpeta FS y sigo sin encontrar nada.

Estas son las fuentes de Linux 0.96 en el que he estado buscando

Cuando dices Linux versión 0.96 a que te refieres exactamente?. Al kernel? A alguna distro en especial?

¿Específicamente qué quieres saber? ¿En qué parte del código fuente de Linux está la gestión de archivos? ¿Donde se almacena la estructura de carpetas? En el último caso, yo creo que es totalmente dependiente del formato de la partición: FAT, NTFS, EXT, etc. Te dejo algunos links de interés https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/latest/filesystems/index.html https://blogs.oracle.com/linux/post/understanding-ext4-disk-layout-part-1

Acabo de darme cuenta que tu enlace apunta a las fuentes del kernel versión 0.96. Tal y como estaba parecía el enlace de donde habías sacado la imagen. He editado la pregunta para reflejarlo, pero si lo he mal interpretado, por favor, dímelo y elimina la edición (en caso de que se apruebe)

@RevistaOnlineOccam'sRazor gracias, esa era mi intencion

La estructura de directorios de un sistema basado en el kernel Linux es independiente del kernel. Se trata de un convenio acordado por todos los programas que funcionan en el sistema y que se recoge en el denominado Filesystem Hierarchy Standard o Estándard de Jerarquía del Sistema de Ficheros, normalmente conocido como LHS.
Excepciones a esto son el /proc y /sys. Estos pseudo sistemas de ficheros se utilizan para intercambiar información con el kernel y si podrás encontrar código, al menos para crear entradas en ellos... Pero no en la versión 0.96 ya que fueron introducidos mucho más tarde. Sin embargo, es posible compilar el kernel para no utilizar esos pseudo filesystems.
Simplificando el proceso de arranque; tras la gestión del boot, el kernel se carga en memoria y comienza a ejecutarse. Inicializa varias cosas y eventualmente monta el sistema de ficheros raíz para ejecutar el programa init (normalmente primero monta un disco RAM y luego hace el pivot_root al disco físico). A partir de ahí es cosa del espacio de usuario que las cosas se encuentren en un lugar o en otro.
Así que resumiendo. No vas a encontrar en ningún kernel Linux código para generar la estructura de directorios del sistema. Esa estructura es un convenio definido en el FHS.
Espero que esto te ayude.

entonces si no esta definido en el kernel de linux, entonces sabes donde se implementan y se crean todo este árbol jerárquico de directorios ?

Los directorios se crean durante el proceso de instalación. Específicamente durante la instalación de los paquetes. Cada paquete define la ruta en la que copiar cada fichero que contiene. El proceso de instalación del paquete crea los directorios necesarios. Puedes echar un ojo a el proceso de instalación de Arch.. veras que tras formatear simplemente se instalan los paquetes

Especifica más tu pregunta. No obstante, hay una aplicación llamada tree que la puedes instalar independientemente de que distro estés usando. Al ejecutar tree sobre un directorio, se mostrará toda la estructura jerárquica del mismo en forma de árbol mostrando todo lo que este contiene (subidrectorios y archivos), es una aplicación de consola. Pruébala y mira a ver si resuelve lo que quieres.
Aquí te dejo una muestra de como instalarlo en estás distros, si usas otra busca como instalarlo para esa:
$ sudo pacman -S tree # Arch Linux
$ yum install tree -y #Centos y Fedora
$ sudo apt-get install tree # Ubuntu  
$ sudo aptitude install tree # Debian

